# Find duplicates in dataframe and group them by assigning a key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I´ve looked around and found similar questions but none of them really helped me to find a solution.
I want my script to read a csv which looks like this:

```
hot_dict = {'Links': links, 'Titles': titles, 'Datestamps': datestamp_extended,'GroupID': ""  }
```

I want to find all duplicate links in column links and assign all links that are identical the same key in column "GroupID"

| Links | GroupID |
| --- | --- |
| A | Key1 |
| B | Key2 |
| A | Key1 |
| B | Key2 |

This gives me just true and false values obviously:

```
df['GroupID'] =df.duplicated(subset=['Links'], keep=False)
```

Is there an elegant way to continue from here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the first A has key1 and the second A has key2 , what key should be in the new  A ?

Comment: Also Key1. I want to replace the link with an easier to work with value (like an Integer) that some rows may share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple key with an integer ID, you can first convert the Links column to [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), then just obtain the category code from that:

```
df['GroupID'] = df['Links'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: Awesome! One more question. Now I get an additional unnamed column which also has the desired keys but with different integers in it. Why is that and how do I prevent it?

Comment: In theory that shouldn't happen with this code alone. Are you doing something different than the code snipped I posted?

Comment: This is the code I´m using: 
`df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\dataframe.csv', encoding='utf_8')
df['GroupID'] = df['Links'].astype('category').cat.codes
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\dataframe.csv', encoding='utf_8',index=True)`

Comment: So the additional column you are talking about is the column you get in the saved csv file? If yes, that's probably the index. Replace the `to_csv` call to: `df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\dataframe.csv', encoding='utf_8',index=False)` (notice: `index=False`). This tells pandas to not save the index column in the csv file. Also, apparently you are reading and writing the same csv file, so also delete the index column from the data frame you read, if it's there from the start.

Comment: Ok this is weird. I executed the code 5 times in a row to see what happens. From the 2nd execution on it seems like you are right and it is the index but when I turn the index to false it still gives me new column.

Comment: Is the extra column already there after you read the data frame with `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\dataframe.csv', encoding='utf_8')`? Since you read and overwrote the same file before it's possible that it's there from previous executions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244353/discussion-between-user2246849-and-maxfrost).